# VS2010/Windows 7 -> can't connect to ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webdev.webserver

I have a clean installation of Windows 7 with VS2010 RTM and am trying to get the ASP.NET Development Server to work.

When I run the project, the WebDev server starts and shows that it's listening on port x on localhost.

I've tried:

- `telnet` to the port. The port is not listening.
- running `netstat -o` shows that the WebDev server is in fact not listening on any port.
- manually changing the WebDev port to a different port and restarted VS without effect.

I have Windows Firewall turned off entirely and am not running any other firewall software either.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you attempt to access a page within the web application project? Does the WebDev server return the proper response?

Comment: do you mean accessing the page in design view? Yes, that works. I think something funky is going on with IPv6. I turned off IPv6 on the NIC but when I ping localhost it's responding with IPv6 address. Since the WebDev server tries to listen on localhost, I think it fails to bind if to the proper IPv4 address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, figured out how to fix it: For some reason my hosts file had "127.0.0.1       localhost" commented, so I'm assuming WebDev server tried to bind to localhost but it couldn't resolve to the 127.0.0.1 address. After I uncommented that line and restarted VS, the WebDev server works fine

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't need localhost to be in the hosts file to be resolved. However if you issued a "route delete *" previously, localhost won't be resolved anymore.

Comment: I didn't and this is a clean Windows 7 install, so I'm a little puzzled why it wouldn't resolve. Don't quite understand though what a route table entry has to do with the DNS resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and tried the above, but it did not work. After a few mins looking around I realised someone had turned on internet connection sharing - turned this off and then all worked well again.